# Почему на маленьких экранах текст съезжает?

Tags: android, xml

Сделал кнопку в ней текст , но когда запускаю на экранах входящих в диапазон Small, например Nexsus_s, текст становится в две строки. На сколько я знаю размер текста не спроста считается в `sp`  и должен сам масштабироваться. Ну выходит дело в том, что моя кнопка позволяет тексту расползтись.  Если вместо 28  dp высоту установлю по содержимому, то кнопка становится слишком большая.

```
` <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/anim_button"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/button_sort_name3"
                android:textSize="14sp" />`
```

Вот вся верстка целиком:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListOfCurrencies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/currency"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerCurrency"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ListOfCurrencies"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Current_Date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClickDate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:textSize="24sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/anim_button"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/button_sort_name1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/anim_button"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/button_sort_name2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/anim_button"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/button_sort_name3" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="mobiledimension.exchangerates.FragmentAct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Получается на маленьком экране вот так : https://gyazo.com/33a89a7d85c5b06f5affadc6a918fff1
А на больших: https://gyazo.com/1d24ac4d8f0d463f74b4f092aadfab24

Comment: скорей всего другие элементы выталкивают этот, у вас же стоит Wrap а вес 1, лежит в Linear. Вы покажите полностью верстку и покажите как съезжает.

Comment: sp - не спроста, а для того, чтобы учитывать настройки системы по размеру шрифтов. То есть, если в настройках телефона стоит "большой текст", то размер текста, указанный в sp будет увеличиваться, а указаный в dp - нет, а не для того, чтобы масштабироваться в маленькие виджеты.

Comment: Shwarz Andrei, да , всё как вы сказали. Вес  1 для всех элементов LinaerLoyaut ведь означает, что элементы должны разделить место поровну. И вроде так и получается, но текст длинный чтобы поместиться на маленьком экране используя такой же размер шрифта. Я думал, что шрифт тоже должен уменьшиться.

Comment: pavlofff, мм, не знал этого. Значит , чтобы текст изменялся в соответствии с разрешением экрана, надо использовать dp , но после этого текст перестанет меняться в соответствии с предпочтениями пользователя. Странно, мне кажется теоретически можно было реализовать так чтобы текст изменялся в зависимости от разрешения и одновременно учитывал и предпочтения пользователя.

Comment: А ну так оно и есть. Sp по определению и масштабируется в зависимости от предпочтений пользователя и в зависимости от плотности экрана. Поэтому мне не понятно, почему текст съезжает

Comment: сам уменьшится он точно никак не должен. и да, sp - те же dp, но учитывает и настройки системы.

Comment: @pavlofff, какими способами можно сделать так, чтобы текст влезал во View независимо от размеров и положения экрана?

Comment: @КириллМалышев [указывать dimens на размер шрифта](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620551/7566397) для проблемных плотностей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит из за того, что текст целиком не входит в границы, указанные для виджета и система удаляет текст начиная от последнего пробела (зачем она так делает - вопрос филосовский).

Есть несколько способов решить эту проблему (текст должен быть в одну строку, но на маленьких экранах он не входит):

1) Для маленьких экранов выводить другой текст (более короткая фраза, сокращения)

Преимущества: заранее известный результат, нормальный размер текста для чтения
Недостатки: явных нет

Создаем папку *res/values-hdpi/* (или с другим квалификатором, на плотности которого имеются проблемы с текстом)

создаем там файл *strings.xml* где пишем альтернативный, более короткий текст

```
<resources>
    <string name="some_text">по возрст.</string>
</resources>
```

Для виджета указываем текст в виде ресурса:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@string/some_text"/>
```

2) Доверяем сокращение системе:

Достоинства: то же, что и первый вариант
Недостатки: неизвестно, как именно сократит система и будет ли это понятно в итоге

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

3) Уменьшаем размер текста для проблемного экрана

Достоинста: сохраняется весь текст
Недостатки: чтобы вместить весь текст, шрифт может быть очень маленький и плохо читаться

Создаем папку *res/values-hdpi/*

создаем там файл *dimens.xml* где указываем размер текста

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="small_size">10sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Указываем значение для виджета:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textSize="@dimen/small_size"/>
```

4) Используем более компактную компоновку экрана, например в вашем случае можно использовать `Spinner` с выбором вариантов сортировки

[image: scrn]

PS: Для первого и третьего вариантов так же обязательно должно быть указано значение по умолчанию, которое необходимо поместить в папку без квалификаторов (*res/values/*), файлы оформляются аналогично, значения в файлах соотвествуют нормальным условиям: текст - "по возрастанию", размер шрифта - 14sp, например.